# Showing that $\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{k_i}{2} \leq \binom{n-m}{2}$ when $k_0 + \ldots + k_m = n$

Tags: combinatorics

I came across the following inequality (well, it's in a paper, I am assuming it is correct for now...).

Let $n$ be a positive integer and suppose $k_0 + \ldots + k_m = n$, $k_i > 0$. Then $\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{k_i}{2} \leq \binom{n-m}{2}$. I'm trying to think of a combinatorial argument for this inequality, but so far nothing reasonable comes to mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have $m+1$ rooms numbered $0$ through $m$. For $j=0,\ldots,m$, Room $j$ contains $k_j-1$ men and one woman. Then $\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{k_j}2$ is the number of ways of selecting two people from the same room. Now remove the women from Rooms $1$ through $m$, leaving a total of $n-m$ people in the $m+1$ rooms; $\binom{n-m}2$ is the number of ways of selecting two of these $n-m$ people. The inequality is immediate if we can exhibit an injection from the first set of pairs into the second.

To do this, first send each pair of men to itself. If $W$ is the woman remaining in Room $0$, also send every pair consisting of $W$ and one of the men in Room $0$ to itself. The only pairs left unaccounted for in the domain are the mixed pairs drawn from Rooms $1$ through $m$; to get the image of one of these pairs under the injection, replace the female member of the pair with $W$. It’s not hard to check that this map is injective.

Comment: Thanks! You are amazing! :)

Comment: @muffle: You’re welcome! I just like combinatorial arguments; they’re fun.